# Graph API filter calendar and room request?

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I work with the new Microsoft Graph API python sdk and want to retrieve room lists and calendar events related to them. I managed to get a list of rooms and related calendar events but I would like to do some filtering on those, essentially:

1. Find rooms only on a certain floor
2. Find rooms only wheelchairs accessible
3. Find rooms containing a certain keyword in the name
4. Get all booked events for those rooms within a start and stop datetime.

Any idea how I can add filtering to the calls?

I use:
´graph_client.places.graph_room.get()´ to get the rooms and their associated emails.
´graph_client.users.by_user_id(room_mail).calendar.events.get()´ to get calendar events.

But it is unclear how to filter using those (and documentation for python is basically inexistant from what I saw so far)

Here is the code so far:

```py
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    
    import asyncio
    from msgraph.generated.models.room import Room
    from msgraph.generated.users.item.calendar.get_schedule.get_schedule_request_builder import GetScheduleRequestBuilder
    from msgraph.generated.users.item.calendar.get_schedule.get_schedule_post_request_body import GetSchedulePostRequestBody
    from msgraph import GraphServiceClient
    
    from azure.identity import DeviceCodeCredential, CertificateCredential, AuthorizationCodeCredential

    config = {
      'client_id': '<something>',
      'tenant_id': '<something>',
      'client_secret': '<something>',
      'authority': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<something>',
      'scope': ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'],
      'certificate_path': 'msal_crt_n_key.pem',
    }
    async def get_schedule_for_room(graph_client, mail):
    result = await graph_client.users.by_user_id(mail).calendar.events.get()
    return result

    async def get_rooms(graph_client):
        return await graph_client.places.graph_room.get()
    
    async def main():
        # azure.identity.aio
        print("Login using certificate")
        credential = CertificateCredential(
            tenant_id=config['tenant_id'],
            client_id=config['client_id'],
            certificate_path=config['certificate_path'])
    
        graph_client = GraphServiceClient(credential, config['scope']) # type: ignore
        print("Get list of rooms")
        rooms = await get_rooms(graph_client)
        print(f"Rooms: {rooms}")
    
        room_emails = [r.email_address for r in rooms.value]
        print(f"Rooms emails: {room_emails}")
    
        for mail in room_emails:
            calendar = await get_schedule_for_room(graph_client, mail)
            print(calendar)
            print(type(calendar))
    
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find rooms only on a certain floor

- Query

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room?$filter=floorNumber eq 2
```

- Code snippet for the Python SDK

```
query_params = GraphRoomRequestBuilder.GraphRoomRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
            filter = "floorNumber eq 2",
    )
    
request_configuration = GraphRoomRequestBuilder.GraphRoomRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(
    query_parameters = query_params,
    )
    
result = await client.places.graph_room.get(request_configuration = request_configuration)
```

2. Find rooms only wheelchairs accessible

- Query

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room?$filter=isWheelChairAccessible eq true
```

- Code snippet for the Python SDK

```
query_params = GraphRoomRequestBuilder.GraphRoomRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
        filter = "isWheelChairAccessible eq true",
)

request_configuration = GraphRoomRequestBuilder.GraphRoomRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(
        query_parameters = query_params,
)

result = await client.places.graph_room.get(request_configuration = request_configuration)
```

3. Find rooms containing a certain keyword in the name

- Query

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room?$filter=contains(displayName,'xxx')
```

- Code snippet for the Python SDK

```
query_params = GraphRoomRequestBuilder.GraphRoomRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
        filter = "contains(displayName,'xxx')",
)

request_configuration = GraphRoomRequestBuilder.GraphRoomRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(
query_parameters = query_params,
)


result = await client.places.graph_room.get(request_configuration = request_configuration)
```

4.Get all booked events for those rooms within a start and stop datetime.

- Query
  I would use [calenderView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint where you can specify start and end date time

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/room_email_address/calendarView?startDateTime=2023-08-25T00:00:00Z&endDateTime=2023-08-31T00:00:00Z
```

- Code snippet for the Python SDK

```
query_params = CalendarViewRequestBuilder.CalendarViewRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
        startDateTime = "2023-08-25T00:00:00Z",
        endDateTime = "2023-08-31T00:00:00Z",
)

request_configuration = CalendarViewRequestBuilder.CalendarViewRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(
query_parameters = query_params,
)


result = await client.users.by_user_id('room_email_address').calendar_view.get(request_configuration = request_configuration)
```

Use these imports

```
from msgraph.generated.places.graph_room.graph_room_request_builder import GraphRoomRequestBuilder

from msgraph.generated.users.item.calendar.calendar_view.calendar_view_request_builder import CalendarViewRequestBuilder
```

Comment: How do I import RoomRequestBuilder and CalendarViewRequestBuilder? I can't locate them in the package

Comment: @Kodsama Updated the answer which imports to use. It's quite tricky because SDK has more request builders with the same name.

Comment: Yes I saw that @user2250152, this package is huge...

Comment: Can't find from msgraph.generated.models.users.item.calendar.calendar_view.calendar_view_request_builder though, it seems .users is not in my package (vmsgraph-sdk                          1.0.0a14)

Comment: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python/blob/main/msgraph/generated/users/item/calendar_view/calendar_view_request_builder.py

Comment: @Kodsama try msgraph.generated.users.item.calendar.calendar_view.calendar_view_request_builder